# Combobox displays the wrong content

Tags: combobox

I'm using Access. I'm programming in vba.

When I first load my form a combobox displays content from the wrong column. If I go into design view and come back to form view, the combobox then displays content from the correct column. I have looked at the format strings, but they specify the correct column. I've tried to bind the correct column. I've tried to requery the combobox.

In the application a procedure references a service and a task. We have a table where a service was requested for a particular patient. A patient can request up to three distinct services. Those services each have a task associated with them.  The user selects a patient. The patient has an associated patient request id. This id is used in a query to select the requested services. The user then selects a procedure or a service and task to select a unique row in the table.

The combobox for selecting the procedure is the one having problem.

When a procedure is selected, 1) the appropriate ids for the service and task table are saved in a text field, 2) the appropriate columns in the service and task comboboxes are bound, then 3) the ids in the text fields are assigned as the indexes of the service and task comboboxes.

When a service and subsequent task are selected, the procedure id is saved to a text box, the appropriate column is bound, and the index is assigned to the procedure code combobox. All of that works fine.

I do end up leaving the columns bound. I tried to set them to zero after processing, but that messed up things. binding is about assigning indexes. The Format string should be controlling the content displayed in a given combobox.

How can I force the first combobox to display what it is supposed to display without cycling views?

I've tried to cycle view pro grammatically, but it generates errors when you try to do it with me.

After additional testing, I believe that the column binding is causing the problem. Weird things have happened due to column bindings. I had set them to 0 to eliminate those problems, but the id assignment has me binding the comboboxes again.

David Locke

Comment: You might want to mention which language you're writing this in, sample code that illustrates your problem, and also what you've tried (in terms of code). You did explain your issue but people on SO can't really help you without knowing more about your problem. (Also, welcome to SO)

Comment: I've decided to add an ID column to the query for each combobox. Then, I can bind to the appropriate column and assign values in the normal way. Thanks.